# Get BIOS Time in Java

Tags: java, datetime, operating-system, bios

Is there a way in Java to get the BIOS date and time?

Does Java use the **BIOS** (Basic Input/Output System) Datetime when you call `java.util.Calendar.getInstance()` or `new java.util.Date()?`

I do know that Java somehow works the current Date and time using *January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT* as a base.

But how exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It asks the operating system, which may or may not ask the BIOS.

These dates are based on that *epoch* in this way:

```
new Date(0); // == Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT 1970
```

Comment: +1, like to add that from Javas perspective no such thing as a BIOS does even exist. Java should be running everywhere, no matter if there is a BIOS or not.

Answer (score 5):

There are ways, but these are not portable. One way is to call [hwclock](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hwclock) from your java program via [Runtime.exec()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) and parse the output of hwclock (Linux). Other ways would be using the [JNI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) and do a system call.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these use `System.currentTimeMillis()` which obtains the GMT time from the OS.  The OS may in turn get the time from the BIOS but that is up to the OS.